# Tableau - showing sums and percentages in columns

Tags: tableau-api

I am interested in creating a table that contains both sums and percentages for a collection of measures.  The values should be presented side-by-side.  So, I can can easily generate counts for all measures.

[image]

I can then duplicate the sheet and easily generate row percentages.

[image]

How do I get these values side-by-side on the same chart -- something like:

```
                     G1             G2             G3                 G4

Gender-Male     4,557 40.38%    4,387 37.78%    1,349  11.73%    1,301  10.11%
Gender-Female   4,694 37.71%    4,586 39.92%    1,497  12.13%    1,053  10.24%
```

...

Comment: Few clarification : Are G1, G2 Part of same dimension or They are different measures . Can you please provide some sample data to work upon. Else, if they are separate measure then you might need to calculate %_Measure for each G_measure . Then Place them one below another .

Comment: G1, G2, G3, G4 are all part of the same dimension (care type).  It sounds like I will have to break these apart so they are separate if I understand your comment.  I will update my post shortly to include some data.

Comment: (depending on your data format) but I would have thought that you could just create a secondary sum variable (i.e. through create calculated field) and then have one as the # and the other as the % total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

Firstly you'll need couple of calculated fields :

1: `Percentage of Total` =`sum(value)/total(sum(value))*100`

2: For getting the `CSV` like your output

```
str(sum([Value]))+' , '+left(str([% Of Total]),6)+'%'
```

To get the output something like this:

[image]

However I wouldn't suggest this : like `Measure`,`% of Measure` .

Instead Ideally you should just use the tableau calculation

Which looks like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes Table calculation would do that .

Please check the solution at :

https://public.tableau.com/profile/publish/34558348/Sheet5#!/publish-confirm

Also, you need to uncheck `show header` for `Measure Names`

[image]